# Правильная формулировка «Ответ с рейтингом 100 и более баллов»

Tags: обсуждение, локализация

Дорогие коллеги, помогите, пожалуйста, определиться с правильным переводом английской фразы «Answer score of 100 or more». Мы сходимся на том, что фраза будет построена как «Ответ с (таким-то) рейтингом». Но есть тонкости, которые я хотел бы и поставить на голосование.

В ответах приведены варианты перевода. Пожалуйста, проголосуйте за понравившийся вам вариант или варианты.

Comment: Часть вопроса озвучена на rus.SO: [«Сто и более» или «сто или более»?](http://rus.stackexchange.com/q/419288/5006) Ознакомьтесь с мнением экспертов и там.

Comment: Контекст: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1664/181472

Comment: Для голосования переходим в [соседний вопрос](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1680/178988) - в этом уже не разберёшься.

Comment: > Ответ набрал 100 голосов См. [Улучшение перевода термина score/рейтинг](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1707/23044)

Comment: @jfs: может быть +110 -10, строго говоря это не 100 голосов.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: человеческая речь это не math. Если очень захотеть можно и как -100 голосов эту цифру интерпретировать. Но большинство всё же как сумму голосов это воспримут в контексте получения знака.

Answer (score 14):

> Ответ с рейтингом 100 или более.

"Баллы" можно убрать, и так понятно, о чём речь.

Answer (score 2):

> Ответ с рейтингом 100 или более баллов

Answer (score 2):

> Ответ с рейтингом 100 и более баллов

Answer (score 2):

> Ответ набрал 100 баллов рейтинга

Comment: Можно ещё немного переформулировать, но общая идея этого варианта - что набрано определённое значение. Часть "и более" в любом виде выкидывается, поскольку если он набрал больше, то был момент, когда он набрал ровно столько и за это и был дан знак.

Comment: Хм.. Пожалуй, переформулировал: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1677/178988

Answer (score 1):

> Ответ с рейтингом ⩾100 баллов

Comment: Всё-таки описание должно быть текстом, а не математическими знаками.

Comment: @Qwertiy тогда и число прописью сделать :)

Answer (score 1):

> Ответ достиг рейтинга (в) 100 баллов

Comment: надеюсь, не против моего изменения?

Comment: @Qwertiy нет. Вариант в любом случае не лучший.

Answer (score -1):

> Рейтинг ответа достиг 100 баллов

Comment: @Vlad, ещё вариант - поставь плюсик за меня :)

Comment: Окей, тогда поставь и за меня на «и» и «⩾»

Comment: Это наверное не очень подходит к контексту значка? Речь идёт об условии его получения по идее. В этом контексте скорее «Рейтинг одного из ваших ответов достиг 100 баллов».

Comment: Ответил на ваш призыв в чате. )

Comment: @VladD, на И я и сам поставил. А со знаком не не нравится - я ему уже минус поставил - убрать система не позволяет, т. к. час прошёл. В общем, получается, ты в голосовании не участвуешь))

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1624/Голосовать-за-свои-сообщения-на-мете - хм.. а если свои общие?

Comment: @VladD, «Рейтинг одного из ваших ответов достиг 100 баллов» - длинновато - краткость - сестра таланта :)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Отредактировал ответ со знаком.

Comment: @VladD, ok - убрал минус :)

Answer (score -1):

Ответ набрал более 99 очков:)
Или 100+ очков

Comment: Дело в том, что с переводом слова score наша переводческо-бюрократическая машина уже определилась. :)

Comment: Да по-фиг. Моё дело - предложить, ваше - отказаться:)

Answer (score -2):

> Ответ набрал как минимум 100 баллов рейтинга

Comment: Тут фраза "как минимум" уводит фокус от главного - 100.

Comment: Ещё есть вариант "не менее", но порча акцента от этого не меняется.

Comment: А мне нравится "как минимум". Оригинальная языковая конструкция, в английском вроде бы нет такой.