# Формулируем «100 и более баллов» :: Часть 1

Tags: обсуждение, локализация

Вопрос [Правильная формулировка «Ответ с рейтингом 100 и более баллов»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1671/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC-100-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2/1678?noredirect=1#comment4806_1678) превратился в кашу. Пробуем сделать то же самое, но по этапам.

## Часть 1.
Хотим ли мы видеть любое упоминание "и более" в тексте?

Очевидно, что описание знаков должно быть кратким. При этом, упоминание того, что можно набрать большее количество баллов, полезной нагрузки практически не несёт. Раз есть возможность сформулировать описания без этого куска - то давайте ей и воспользуемся?

Примеры не являются окончательными - они показывают суть идеи. Для победившей категории будет предложено ещё голосование, в котором она будет разделена по следующему признаку. Так будет продолжаться некоторое время до момента, когда чётко можно будет несколько лучших вариантов, за которые можно будет голосовать непосредственно.

---

Пожалуйста, голосуйте только за предпочитаемый вариант, но не против остальных. Иначе голосование получится неравным: одни участники продвинут ответ на 1 балл, а другие на два. Если же мы все начнем голосовать против не-предпочитаемых вариантов, то вся Мета будет в глубоком минусе.

---

На момент принятия ответа:

- Часть "и более" НЕ нужна    +4   -3
- Часть "и/или более" нужна   +3   -2
- Так нельзя голосовать          +2   -0

Comment: Для обсуждения: у нас на данный момент есть строка «Highest scoring answer that outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x» с переводом «Ответ с наилучшим рейтингом, который обошёл более чем вдвое принятый ответ с рейтингом больше 10». Хотим ли мы убрать «больше» и из этого перевода?

Comment: @VladD, давай пока не усложнять?

Comment: Ну, хм. Просто если делать правильно, то стоит делать единообразно.

Comment: @VladD, кстати, там нет "вдвое и более" - там "более чем в двое". Если принятый ответ набрал 11, а твой 22 - то ты получаешь знак, или тебе надо хотя бы 23? И тот же вопрос про 10 и 11 - там тоже говорится строго больше. А в случае с сотнями у нас явно 100 достаточно и мы городим какой-то огород вокруг "больше или равно".

Comment: Угу, это ошибка перевода. Подправлю, пока не забылось.

Comment: @VladD, в английском варианте у тебя тоже строго больше ;)

Comment: Хм :-\ Может, тогда не нужно было править, нужно именно 23? Переспрошу-ка у Николаса.

Comment: @VladD там строго более чем вдвое и более 11. То есть минимальные требования это принятый 11, получатель знака 23.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, значит его не трогаем :)

Comment: Окей, вернул исходный текст.

Comment: Вопросу-то за что минус? Всё по согласованию с @Vlad [в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25110286#25110286)

Comment: А кто поставил минус вопросу? Объясните, что не так.

Comment: @VladD это я сгоряча, но решил что правильнее будет возразить ответом. Минус снял. )

Comment: @VladD согласен. Кроме 11/23 там ещё десяток таких знаков и все должны обсуждаться вместе.

Comment: А можно всё именовать SQL-запросами: `select count(answers.id) from answers where answers.rating >= 100 group by ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Часть "и более" НЕ нужна.

Если ответ достиг чего-то большего, то, очевидно, был момент, в который он достиг ровно эту грань. Мы же не даём знак за каждый последующий балл, важно именно достижение грани.

Примеры формулировок:

- Ответ преодолел рубеж в 100 баллов.
- Ответ достиг рейтинга 100 баллов.
- Рейтинг ответа достиг 100 баллов.
- Ответ набрал 100 баллов рейтинга.
- Ответ набрал рейтинг 100 баллов.
- Ответ набрал рейтинг в 100 баллов.
- Ответ набрал 100 баллов.
- Один из ответов набрал 100 баллов.

Answer (score 2):

Я считаю, что так нельзя голосовать, потому что язык не подчиняется простым комбинаторным методам. В каких-то вариантах "и более" подразумевается:

- Рейтинг ответа достиг 100 [баллов] (если имеет больше, значит когда-то ранее достиг ста)

В других необходимо явно обозначать интервал:

- Ответ, имеющий сто или более баллов рейтинга. (Новичку может быть непонятно: вдруг надо выбить строго сто? )

Нельзя оценить эти варианты без контекста.

Аналогичный пример вопросов:

- Вы предпочитаете хлеб с мясом или без мяса?
- Вы предпочитаете хлеб с вареньем или без варенья?

Я - дважды за хлеб с добавками, но варенья с мясом не хочу.

Comment: Именно поэтому мы голосуем сначала за "хлеб с добавкой или хлеб без добавки?", а уже после этого будем выбирать "добавка должна быть мясом, вареньем, маслом  или мёдом?". Даже не так. "Добавка должна быть сладкой?" - Да - "Вареньем или мёдом?" Правильная абстракция и правильный порядок решают всё. Мы как раз выбираем, является ли предпочтительным вариант, в котором "и более" подразумевается неявно, или в котором его следует проговорить явно. Ни в коем случае не предлагается взять и просто выбросить этот кусок из фразы, в которой он нужен. И примеры в ответах подобраны соответствующие.

Comment: Т. е. ты как раз привёл то же деление на явное/неявное, за которое мы тут голосуем. Оно есть и ты сам это видишь. Так что же мешает голосовать на его основе? В данном случае оно наиболее значительное, поэтому и выбрано для первого голосования.

Comment: @Qwertiy после первого решения некоторые из отвергнутых вариантов будут лучше, чем некоторые из оставшихся. То есть мне в последнем раунде придется выбирать между ветчиной, свининой и говядиной, а в моем личном рейтинге лидируют, например, говядина, помидор и мёд. А выберут колбасу. :(

Comment: Но накидать два десятка вариантов и сказать голосуйте - это тоже не выход. Личный рейтинг вообще никак не учитывается, кроме того, что ты можешь поставить +1, 0 и -1. Специальной системы ранжирования вариантов каждым пользователем тут нет. Так что приходится так. Можно на последнем этапе добавить пункт типа против всех и если в нём наберётся много голосов, то смотреть по комментариям к нему и переформировать итоговый список. Но выбор не должен быть из слишком большого числа вариантов.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, обычно вариантов бывает немного. Вообще, много голосований это плохо, демократия опасна тем, что большинство всегда некомпетентно :) Надеюсь, нам это не слишком повредит.

Comment: @Qwertiy по-прежнему считаю, что такие методы неприменимы к языку.

Answer (score 1):

## Часть "и/или более" нужна.

Некоторые формулировки просто кажутся странными без неё.
Да и так сделано в английском варианте.

Примеры формулировок:

- Ответ с рейтингом 100 или более.
- Ответ с рейтингом 100 или более баллов.
- Ответ с рейтингом 100 и более баллов.
- Ответ с рейтингом ⩾100 баллов.
- Ответ набрал как минимум 100 баллов рейтинга.
- Ответ набрал не менее 100 баллов рейтинга.
- Ответ набрал более 99 баллов. // Прям как ценник в магазине)))