# Формулируем «100 и более баллов» :: Часть 2

Tags: обсуждение, локализация

#### Часть 1.
Хотим ли мы видеть любое упоминание "и более" в тексте?
*[Нет](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1680/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC-100-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-1)*

А теперь продолжение:

## Часть 2
Хотим ли мы акцентировать внимание на слове "Ответ", поставив его на первое место?

Первое слово в описании знака акцентирует внимание на неком предмете или действии. Вероятно, в случае достижения ответом 100-балльного рейтинга следует акцентировать внимание на слове "ответ".

Примеры не являются окончательными - они показывают суть идеи. Для победившей категории будет предложено ещё голосование, в котором она будет разделена по следующему признаку. Так будет продолжаться некоторое время до момента, когда чётко можно будет несколько лучших вариантов, за которые можно будет голосовать непосредственно.

---

Как написал @NickVolynkin в прошлом голосовании:

> Пожалуйста, голосуйте только за предпочитаемый вариант, но не против остальных. Иначе голосование получится неравным: одни участники продвинут ответ на 1 балл, а другие на два. Если же мы все начнем голосовать против не-предпочитаемых вариантов, то вся Мета будет в глубоком минусе.

Answer (score 4):

Вообще-то в прошлом вопросе победил вариант **"Против такого способа голосовать за переводы"**. Повторю его здесь.

Считаю более удачным простой способ - предлагать все варианты одним списком, желательно в контексте.

- По одиночке их удобно сравнивать между собой. А для множеств переводов оператор сравнения не определен.
- В числе лучших часто оказываются синтаксически очень различные варианты.

Comment: Ну не то чтоб победил. Прочто единственный не собрал минусов. А по числу плюсов он на последнем месте. Ты ж сам говорил, минусы не ставить.

Answer (score 1):

## Да, слово "ответ" должно быть первым

Вероятно, имеет смысл акцентировать внимание именно на слове "ответ", поскольку знак получен именно за ответ, причём конкретный ответ, а не "один из ответов". Акцентировать внимание на слове рейтинг не имеет смысла, поскольку почти все знаки с числами в описании даются за некий рейтинг, а уникальной часть является именно слово "ответ" или "вопрос".

Примеры формулировок:

- Ответ преодолел рубеж в 100 баллов.
- Ответ достиг рейтинга 100 баллов.
- Ответ набрал 100 баллов рейтинга.
- Ответ набрал рейтинг 100 баллов.
- Ответ набрал рейтинг в 100 баллов.
- Ответ набрал 100 баллов.
- Ответ с рейтингом 100 баллов.
- Ответ со 100-балльным рейтингом.

Answer (score -1):

## Нет, следует начать описание с чего-то другого

Из возможных вариантов приходят в голову

- сущность "рейтинг" - все знаки с числами 25, 100, 1000 и так далее даются за рейтинг - поставить его на первое место значит сделать их все визуально похожими, что не кажется хорошей идеей - по описанию должно быть с первого взгляда понятно, за что даётся значок
- формулировка "один из ответов" - формально верно, но не очень звучит; к тому же, знак даётся за конкретный ответ и нет смысла добавлять какую-то размытость к описанию
- Пассивное "достигнут" - те же недостатки, что у варианта "рейтинг".
- Акцент на действие "дан ответ" - имеет смысл, но, на мой взгляд, является необоснованным увеличением длины фразы, поскольку слово "дан" можно убрать без потери смысла.

Если имеются ещё идеи, то пишем в комментарии к ответу.

Примеры формулировок:

- Рейтинг ответа преодолел рубеж 100 баллов.
- Рейтинг ответа достиг 100 баллов.
- Один из ответов набрал 100 баллов.
- Достигнут 100-балльный рейтинг ответа
- Дан ответ с рейтингом 100 баллов
- Дан ответ, набравший 100 баллов рейтинга