# "Тривиальный ответ преобразован в комментарий"

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, мета

Попытался добавить вариант для голосования по теме [Правильная формулировка «Ответ с рейтингом 100 и более баллов»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1671/23044)

[Ответ был преобразован в комментарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1671/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bc-100-%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2#comment4950_1671), что нежелательно для вопросов-голосований на Мете.

Comment: Эти вопросы давно все забросили.

Comment: А по теме - согласен. Мне кажется, это нигде не нужно.

Answer (score 3):

Это неправильный вопрос, и у него неправильные ответы. Даже на Мете не должно быть бессмысленных голосований с двумя словами в ответе. Ответы должны быть хотя бы минимально аргументированы.

Если на вопрос нельзя дать осмысленный ответ, то проблема не в преобразовании короткого ответа в комментарий, проблема в вопросе. Учитывая, что вопрос активно обсуждался в чате, и аргументация на самом деле очень даже присутствует, считаю безответственным вынесение голосования на Мету в таком огрызочном виде.

Повторяю: голосованиям "нравится / не нравится" не место на Мете. Аргументация обязательна, даже если выбирается предлог в локализации.

Answer (score -2):

Похоже, что для преобразования в комментарий требуются два условия:

- Очень мало текста
- Есть ссылка.

На основном сайте такой механизм отлично работает. Если в ответе только три слова и ссылка – ему место в комментариях.

На Мете механизм дает осечку: аналогичные короткие ответы без ссылки не преобразуются в комментарии. Не думаю, что это проблема: уже обсуждали, что варианты перевода обязательно нужно предлагать в контексте. Предлагаемый перевод плюс 1-3 предложения для контекста — это уже достаточно текста для нормального ответа.